# Sort by estimate size in ggcoef

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a lot of variables from a multiple regression I would like to visualize. How can I sort by estimate size in the `GGally::ggcoef` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to dig in to the function to change the ordering by the looks of this. When you type `ggcoef` in to the console you can see its arguments and the code that goes inside. I've picked it apart with the sample data you see in `?ggcoef`. Play around with it more to get it in the format you desire. Hope this helps, Jonny

p.s. good thing about this is you can mod it more. I would for instance add `p <- p + theme_minimal()` as I prefer the aesthetics ;)

```
# packages and sample data/model
library(GGally)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

d <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
reg2 <- glm(Survived ~ Sex +  Class + Age, family = binomial, data = d, weights = d$Freq)

# eg with gg coeff
ggcoef(reg2, exponentiate = TRUE, exclude_intercept = TRUE, errorbar_height = .2, color = "blue")


# set defaults
vline <- TRUE
vline_intercept <- "auto"
vline_color <- "gray50"
vline_linetype <- "dotted"
vline_size <- 1
conf.level <- 0.95
conf.int <- TRUE
exponentiate <- FALSE
errorbar_color = "gray25"
errorbar_height = 0
errorbar_linetype = "solid"
errorbar_size = 0.5

# type ggcoef in to the console to get the function. It orders on name with
# no option to change it
x <- broom::tidy(reg2, conf.int = conf.int, conf.level = conf.level, 
                 exponentiate = exponentiate)

# these two lines will change the ordering based on estimate
x$variable <- factor(x$term, levels=unique(as.character(x$term)) )
x <- transform(x, variable = reorder(variable, -estimate) ) 

# rest produce the ggplot in the function. Play around with settings as required
# perhaps rewrite the function with your added arguments and store ;)
p <- ggplot(x, mapping = aes_string(y = "variable", x = "estimate"))

if (vline) {
  if (exponentiate) {
    if (vline_intercept == "auto") {
      vline_intercept <- 1
    }
    p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = vline_intercept, 
                        color = vline_color, linetype = vline_linetype, 
                        size = vline_size) + scale_x_log10()
  }
  else {
    if (vline_intercept == "auto") {
      vline_intercept <- 0
    }
    p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = vline_intercept, 
                        color = vline_color, linetype = vline_linetype, 
                        size = vline_size)
  }
}




if (conf.int & "conf.low" %in% names(x) & "conf.high" %in% 
    names(x)) 
  p <- p + geom_errorbarh(aes_string(xmin = "conf.low", 
                                     xmax = "conf.high"), color = errorbar_color, height = errorbar_height, 
                          linetype = errorbar_linetype, size = errorbar_size)

p <- p + geom_point(aes_string(y = "variable", x = "estimate"))
p
```